# pip show does not show the package but I can import it

Tags: pip

I'm using venv, created by `python3 -m venv .venv`. It's runnig python 3.6.9.

When I run `pip show tensorflow` in venv, it returns `WARNING: Package(s) not found: tensorflow`. However, in a python interpreter, I can import it (still, in venv):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)  # 1.15.0
```

`which python` and `which pip` returns:

```sh
.../.venv/bin/python
.../.venv/bin/pip
```

Additional information: I tried to dockerize this project. When I try to run it, it throw error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`, which I think makes sense, because I don't have it in my `requirements.txt`. But without docker, I can import `tensorflow` both in interpreter and in a module.

I don't know what or which part is wrong here; docker or pip?

Comment: because you are using python 3 you should use --pip3 show tensorflow-- instead.

Comment: with dockerfile you can also use pip3 instead of pip.

Comment: I don't think that's the situation. I'm in a virtualenv which uses `.venv/bin/pip`, so `pip ...` should do all the job. I even tried what you said but it didn't work.